# Remove Aux routes in angular 4 "?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

*I've seen an example where I have two `<router-outlet>` , where only one has a `name` property - so I made a little test :*

I have this router mapping :

```
export  const routing   = [
    {path:'', pathMatch:'full', component:EmptyComponent},
    {path:'dog',   component:DogComponent},
    {path:'bird',   outlet:'under', component:BirdComponent} 
];
```

And I also have this `routerLinks` :

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['']">Clear</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['dog']">Only Dog</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {under: ['bird','' }}]">Only Bird</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['dog',{outlets: {under: ['bird','' }}]">Dog & Bird</a></li>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<hr>
<router-outlet name='under'></router-outlet>
```

**Question:**

If I click `Clear` - I see none (✓)
If I then click `Only Dog` - I only  see a dog (✓)
If I then click `Only Bird` - I see Both Dog and Bird  (✕ - why is that ? I want to see only a Bird)
If I click `Dog & Bird` - I see an error (✕ - *Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dog'* . I'm expecting to see both Dog and a Bird)

Why is that ? And how can I fix my code so that it'll show the exact link description ?

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EnE1G2sNWWYMbSf6lwdX?p=preview)

Related or not - I think it has to do something with clearing an AUX route ( passing null via `routerLink` is not helping. - see [**PLNKR2**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NaSnjDvXcW8zxpYuG04Y?p=preview))

Comment: after the bird sees the dog, the bird will fly away. You should look into that

Comment: I remember a question like this before with a bounty. Was it again you?

Comment: @echonax nope. However I did take the general idea from an online-non-working  plnkr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/2fvbGnepD5tGaeYb8DKK?p=preview

here is the routing. What I understood by reading routing tests when you need navigate at the same with two outlets - use outlets only. for main outlet just use 'primary'.

```
  <li><a [routerLink]="['']">None</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: 'dog', under: null}}]">Only Dog </a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: null, under: ['bird']}}]">Only Bird</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: ['dog'], under: ['bird']}}]">Dog & Bird</a></li>
```

Comment: **Perfect**. Thank you.

Comment: [I have a related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857150/angular-how-can-i-activate-aux-route-with-lazy-loaded-module) problem with outlet can you please have a look ?