# Angular - How can I activate AUX route with lazy loaded module?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have an angular app which is loading lazily module.

At first the app is navigating to `home` where it loads the module ( named `module1`) :

*main routing :*

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", loadChildren: "./module1/module1.module#Module1Module" }, 

];
```

At `module1` - there's also routing table :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "", component: Home1Component,
        children: [
            { path: 'bird', outlet: 'under', component: Home2Component } 
        ]
    }
];
```

So since it's loading lazily , when the app starts - it goes to `/home` where there it loads the `Home1Component`

But `Home1Component` also has a button in it which suppose to set a value to the *outlet  route* .

**home1.component.html:**

```
<input value="click to activate aux route"  type="button" (click)="go()"/>
<router-outlet  ></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='under'></router-outlet>  //<---- I want to activate  only this
```

This is how I try to activate the outlet route :

```
  public go() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { under: ['bird'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route })
  }
```

But I get an error :

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'

**Question :**

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it ?

[**Online code here : Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfirad?file=app/module1/home1/home1.component.ts)

Comment: I believe this is a bug with angular lazy loading aux route. I had a similar issue. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394728/angular-2-lazily-loaded-routes-that-contain-aux-router-outlet/45400430#45400430

Comment: @jmw5598 I see your answer but can you please apply this to my code? Because I dont see how it's going to work

Comment: I can. I'll apply it as soon as I can get in a computer. Might be a few hours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well with the help of @jmw5598 who referenced me to the problem/bug with the router .

There is a problem with default empty location  for lazy loaded modules.

[Here is a working solution for the problem .](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ghbtn?file=app/module1/home1/home1.component.ts)

The key thing to understand is that lazy modules should not have empty root path

[*Related specific description*](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-337162661) :

Comment: Seems to be working great @RoyiNamir. Is there a way to auto load that aux router (bird in your example) when the /home/e1 is loaded, from the routing module? I.e. not use a button or calling the same router method from ngOnInit the parent.